# Why do I get this error when trying to use presentViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitableview, uiactionsheet

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "2Pv-MD-gdY-view-bDF-TR-G6E" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

Why am I getting that? The gist of my app is that I have a UITableViewController with a button that triggers an action sheet. The action sheet, when a specific option is pressed, then presents a view controller (modally). Here's my code:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Text"]) {
        AddTextViewController *addTextViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addTextViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:addTextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

}

I can supply any further needed information, but I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: What type is AddTextViewController? I'm assuming it's NOT a UITableViewController. I assume in your storyboard addTextViewController is a UITableViewController

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a view in a xib for this table view controller? You probably just need to connect the tableView property in the xib file to a tableView.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to instantiate a nib and it isn't present. Is the nib included as a project member?